# Keyframing doesn't work in shader editor on a specific object

Tags: keyframes, shader-nodes

Basically the title. I have an object that I want to keyframe some of its shader nodes of. If I try keyframing a shader node of any other object, it works as expected. Here is an example of what happens when I try to add keyframes and play it back.
[image: example]

Here you can see that the f-curve is indeed enabled and there are no modifiers.
[image: Example 2]

Comment: do you mean that you don't see the keyframes? You need to select the node as you've enabled the Only Show Selected option (blue arrow button in the Graph Editor)

Comment: @moonboots That's actually not what I meant: the keyframes that I inputted also actually don't do anything (alongside the keyframed numbers not showing up in the node). They're always stuck at 0.000

Comment: oh ok yes that's weird, maybe share the file (remove all the useless objects): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Alrighty, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jnD3je2W" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jnD3je2W/)

Comment: Yes I can't keyframe any node in this material, I hope someone will understand why

Comment: @moonboots: same here - i would guess the blend file is "wrecked" - or a blender bug. If i add a new mix color in the same tree, it doesn't work, but if i add a new mix color in another, it works...weird

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, but it's definitely the material. Making a duplicate of the material gives the same error, if I delete the material on the object and give it a new one from scratch, the keyframing works.

Comment: Oof, thank you for your help, everyone. Should I submit this .blend file to Blender's bug tracker and describe my problem there?

Comment: @Snake8Bit Usually the best way to report a bug is to describe the steps on how to reproduce the error, since the way it happens can hint on reasons why it's happening. Since I guess you don't know how to reproduce it and perhaps it might just  have gotten corrupted somehow, I'm not sure if there's a good way to report it. Also when it happened just once and not multiple times the probability of a real bug is quite low instead of just a coincidental series of unfortunate events leading to this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, and while I'm not sure what exactly caused it, [Gordon Brinkmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/99859/gordon-brinkmann) was right in that you can fix it by deleting the shader and remaking it. this may not be a solution for all, but I'm putting it out there for other people who encounter this.